# Liferay custom-sql using IN operator

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 6.1, Tomcat and MySQL. I have a custom-sql sentence for a list portlet. The custom-sql uses two parameters: an array of groupIds and a result limit.

```
SELECT
count(articleId) as count,
...
FROM comments
WHERE groupId IN (?)
GROUP BY articleId
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 0, ?
```

My FinderImpl class has this method:

```
 public List<Comment> findByMostCommented(String groupIds, long maxItems) {

    Session session = null;
    session = openSession();

    String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FIND_MOST_COMMENTS);

    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity("Comment", CommentImpl.class);

    QueryPos queryPos = QueryPos.getInstance(query);
    queryPos.add(groupIds);
    queryPos.add(maxItems);

    List<Comment> queryResult = query.list();

    return queryResult;
}
```

This returns 0 results. If I remove the WHERE IN(), it works.

Is IN a valid operator? If not, how can search within different groups?

Comment: Well, JDBC `PreparedStatement` (which Liferay might use internally) doesn't support passing in arrays for the `IN` clause. It could be because of this. Check if the `QueryPos` object provides any API for doing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps hibernate is quoting your string of groupIds (presumably it is in the form of `"1,2,3,4"` and when hibernate translates this to sql it is putting quotes around it for you?

You may want to try something like this (from Liferay itself):

```
String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FIND_BY_C_C);

sql = StringUtil.replace(sql, "[$GROUP_IDS$]", groupIds);
```

And include `([$GROUP_IDS$])` in place of the `(?)` in your SQL