# Error while Fetching Records using Custom Query in Liferay

Tags: mysql, hibernate, liferay, liferay-6

I am  passing Array of long values and trying to get the relevant records But it is throwing a Error **Positional Parameter is not defined**.

Here is the code

```
    try {
            String list = CustomSQLUtil.get(id of the query);
            SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(list);
            sqlQuery.setCacheable(false);
            QueryPos q=QueryPos.getInstance(sqlQuery);
            q.add(array of long values);
            return processObjectListToEntityList(QueryUtil.list(sqlQuery, getDialect() ,QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS));
   } 
   catch(Exception e){
       log.error("Error while Fetching Records " + e);
   } finally{
        closeSession(session);
   }
```

Query

```
SELECT 
    entity1.name
FROM 
    entityOne as entity1 
JOIN 
    entityTwo as entity2 
WHERE
    entity1.id = entity2.id
AND
    entity2.id IN (?);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816676/liferay-custom-sql-using-in-operator) seems relevant to your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : she is passing string as a parameter while I am passing Array of Long. The solution provided is not the correct way. QueryPos is providing a API to pass array values as parameter in sql query. I got reference from this link http://chingovan.blogspot.in/2016/01/liferay-custom-dynamic-query-with-array.html

Comment: You need to convert your array to CSV (comma separated values) string.

Comment: @ParkashKumar : currently I am writing query in finder class itself and creating csv value and passing it directly in query without using QueryPos. Hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to parse your query to DinamycQuery API instead. This have many benefits as that you dont have to manage the session lifecycle and that you obtaing a List of liferay model objects directly.

An example would be:

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(AssetCategory.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
Property nameProperty = PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("name");
Property groupIdProperty = PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("groupId");
dynamicQuery.add(nameProperty.eq(name));
dynamicQuery.add(groupIdProperty.eq(groupId));
List<AssetCategory> categoriesByName = AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
```

Comment: yes Dynamic Query helps to solve this issue but the Project is demanding to use Custom SQL Query.